# How to target a ul within a div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering how with javascript can I target a ul within a div, to use javascript to add another li to the ul. The problem is that the div has an id, the ul, and subsequent li's do not.

HTML:

```
<div id="topnav">
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./" rel="">Hello |</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.php" rel="" id="current">We Provide |</a></li>
        <li><a href="service_providers.php" rel="">Service Providers</a></li>
</ul>
```

Ordinarily I would just add an id to the ul, but I with the software I'm using that is not an option, I must use javascript to accomplish this task. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myList = document.getElementById('navcontainer').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
// or: var myList = document.querySelector('#navcontainer ul');

var myNewListItem = document.createElement('li');
myNewListItem.textContent = "A New Item";

myList.appendChild(myNewListItem);
```

Comment: Would .innerHTML work after getting the element by id and then by tagname to insert the li?

Comment: Yes, but make sure to append the new content to the old content: `myList.innerHTML = myList.innerHTML + "<li>A New Item</li>";`

Answer (score 4):

try using `querySelector`

```
var ulElement = document.querySelector( "#navcontainer ul" )
```

Comment: simple and easy to understand thanks